# How to separate tokens(parantheses,colons,etc) when a scanner is scanning a file?

Tags: python, parsing, command-line-arguments

I have created a Python scanner that is a lexical analyzer with created dictionaries. An argument(file) will be passed through command line that will then scan and print out each token.
The problem is that if there is no space between tokens, it counts as a single string. Obviously, I do not want that. Is there a way to make a single rule for encountering no white space and create a single whitespace and then continue or will that be a bunch of conditionals for each one?
An example of the command line print out that has the problem.

```
    Line # 2 - Program: hello_world

 Token: Program:, token, 3004
 Token: hello_world, token, 3004
----------------------------------------
 Line # 3 - Author: example

 Token: Author:, token, 3004
 Token: example, token, 3004

# Implement split() for separation
    for word in line.split():

        # Implementation of block comment encounter
        # If encountered, skip

        if tokenize(word).value == 3006:
            self.insideComment = True
            return ""
        if tokenize(word).value == 3007:
            self.insideComment = False
            return ""
        if tokenize(word).value == 3008:
            return (tokenizedLine)
        if tokenize(word).value == 3014:
            self.insideComment == False
            return ""
        
        # If program encounters ':' then white space
        if tokenize(word).value == 3013:
            return...


        #Special characters, other tokens
   "otherTokens": {
    '\"': 3001,
    # cannot start with number
    '\[([a-zA-Z]|([\-]?[0-9]?.[0-9]))+\]': 3002,
    '[\-]?[0-9]': 3003,
    '[a-zA-Z]+': 3004,
    '\(': 3005,
    '\)': 3006,
    '\/\*': 3007,
    '\*\/': 3008,
    '\/\/': 3009,
    '\[\]': 3010,
    '\,': 3011,
    '\s+': 3012,
    ':': 3013, # colon
    

}
```

Comment: In general, you relying on the user's shell to split arguments into words before invoking your program is a bad idea in the first place -- the better practice is to require your software's users to _always_ quote their arguments, so you get a single string no matter what. Unquoted command-line arguments aren't just word-split; they're also subject to glob expansions, so a word can be replaced with a list of filenames that match it when parsed as a glob, or removed entirely if the shell option `nullglob` is set.

Comment: For an example of good practice, look at awk. When someone passes an awk program on the command line, they quote it so it doesn't get mangled by the shell before awk gets a chance to see it: `awk '{print $1}'`, not `awk {print $1}`

Comment: Beyond that, though -- handling whitespace is within the set of common functionality all serious parsers support, so there's no shortage of best-practice examples to follow. I **strongly** suggest using a preexisting, serious parser-generator framework rather than trying to roll your own; there's an enormous amount of academic research that informs the best practices incorporated in modern (and even not-so-modern) tools.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thank you very much for this information. I'm simply trying my hand to understanding scanning/parsing so I decided to attempt to create my own, in some small fashion. I will look into awk as I haven't tried that yet. Again, thank you.

Comment: To be clear, I mentioned awk only as an example of a widely used standard tool that runs a parser on programs it reads from its command line; that may be where its relevance ends.